# Convert an Integer to time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am being supplied a single integer that is supposed to represent an hour. So If it returns 1 it is 1:00 am and so forth on a 24 hour clock,13 for example is 1:00 pm. I need to convert this into time in SQL.

I know in MYSQL they have a function which does this:

SEC_TO_TIME(TheHour*60*60)

Is there an equivalent I can use in SQL? How do I do this?

Comment: What data type and format do you need to be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
select cast(DATEADD(hour, 13, 0) as time)
```

The upside is that it will still work even with negative numbers or values over 24.

Comment: Thank you this work perfectly. For Future people, If my variable is TheHour it is select cast(DATEADD(hour, TheHour, 0) as time)

Answer (score 1):

There are two T-SQL function:

```
DATEFROMPARTS ( year, month, day )
```

and

```
TIMEFROMPARTS ( hour, minute, seconds, fractions, precision )
```

then you can use CONVERT if you need to format it.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- test data
declare @hour_table table(hour_number int)
while (select count(*) from @hour_table) < 24
    begin
        insert into @hour_table(hour_number)
            select count(*) from @hour_table
    end

-- return results with your conversion to time string
select
    hour_number,
    convert(varchar(8),timefromparts( hour_number, 0, 0, 0, 0 ),0) as time_string
from @hour_table
```